# Add to zero...What is it for?

Tags: cobol

Why such code is used in some applications instead of a MOVE?

```
         add 16 to ZERO giving SOME-RESULT
```

I spotted this in professionally written code at several spots.
[Sorce is on this page](http://www.simotime.com/cblvlrc7.htm)

Comment: Interesting - but I really see nothing that would make this preferable to `MOVE 16 TO ZERO`. Depending on the compiler there's also the possibility that this is resolved as a constant calculation and effectively generated as a `MOVE` (you _may_ be able to generate intermediate or assembler code you can look at to check if your compiler resolves this at compile time).
All above is written in the expectation that `SOME-RESULT` has at least two integer positions - because if it isn't the a `MOVE` is different.

Comment: 'Professionaly written code' doesn't mean much. I've seen things in Cobol shops that would curl your hair.

Answer (score 3):

> *Why such code is used in some applications instead of a MOVE?*

```
     add 16 to ZERO giving SOME-RESULT
```

Without seeing more of the code, it appears that it could be a translation of IBM Assembler to COBOL. In particular, the `ZAP` (Zero and Add Packed) instruction may be literally translated to the above instruction,  particularly if `SOME-RESULT` is `COMP-3`. Thus, someone checking the translation could see that the `ZAP` instruction was faithfully translated.

Or, it could be an assembler programmer's idea of a joke.

---

Having seen the code, I also note the use of

```
    subtract some-data-item from some-data-item
```

which is used instead of

```
    move zero to some-data-item
```

This is consistent with operations used with packed decimal fields in IBM Assembly, where there are no other instructions to accomplish "flexible" moves. By flexible, I mean that the packed decimal instructions contain a length field so that specific size `MVC` instructions need not be used.

This particular style, being unusual, may be related to catching copyright violations.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, I'm pretty sure I know the reason why the programmer would have done this. It has something to do with the binary representation of the number.

I bet `SOME-RESULT` is a `packed-decimal` (or `COMP-3`) format number. Let's assume the field is defined like this

```
05 SOME-RESULT          PIC S9(5) COMP-3.
```

This results in a 3-byte field with a hex representation like this

```
x'00016C'
```

The decimal number is encoded as a binary encoded decimal (BCD, one decimal digit per half-byte), and the last half-byte holds the sign.

Let's take a look at how the sign is defined:

- if it is one of x'C', x'A', x'F', x'E' (café), then the number is positive
- if it is one of x'B', x'D', then the number is negative
- any of x'0'..'x'9' are not valid signs, so we can distinguish signed packed-decimals from unsigned.

However, a *zoned* number (`PIC 9(5) DISPLAY`) - as in the source code - looks like this:

```
x'F0F0F0F1F6'
```

As you can see, each decimal digit is an EBCDIC character with the 'zone' part (the first half-byte) always being x'F'.

Now we get closer to your question!

What happens when we use

```
MOVE 16 TO SOME-RESULT
```

If you just `MOVE` a number to such a field, this results in being compiled into a `PACK` instruction on the machine code level.

```
PACK   SOME-RESULT,=C'16'
```

A pack instruction takes a zoned number and packs it by picking only the second half-byte of each byte and storing it in the half-bytes of the packed number - with one exception! When it comes to the last byte, it simply flips the two half-bytes and stores them in the last half-byte of the decimal.

This means that the zone of the last byte of the zoned decimal becomes the sign in the packed decimal:

```
x'00016F'
```

So now we have an x'F' as the sign – which is a valid positive sign.

However, what happens if use this Cobol instruction instead

```
ADD 16 TO ZERO GIVING SOME-RESULT
```

This compiles into multiple machine level instructions

```
PACK   SOME_RESULT,=C'0'
PACK   TEMP,=C'16'
AP     SOME_RESULT,TEMP
```

(or similar - the key point is that is needs an `AP` somewhere)

This makes a slight difference in the result, because the `AP` (add packed) instruction always sets the resulting sign to either x'C' for a positive or x'D' for a negative result.

So the difference lies in the sign

```
x'00016C'
```

Finally, the question is why would one make this difference? After all, both x'F' and x'C' are valid positive signs. So why care?

There is one situation when this slight difference can cause big problems: When the packed decimal is part of an index key, then we would not get a match, even though the numbers are semantically identical!

Because this situation occurred quite often in older databases like VSAM and DL/I (later: IMS/DB), it became good practice to "normalize" packed decimals if they were part of an index key.

However, some programmers adopted the practice without knowing why, so you may come across code that uses this "normalization" even though the data are not used for index keys.

You might also wonder why a compiler does not optimize out the `ADD 16 TO ZERO`. I'm pretty sure it once did, but that broke a lot of applications, so this specific optimization was removed again or at least made a non-default option with warnings.

---

### Additional useful info

Note that at least the Enterprise Cobol for z/OS compiler allows you to see exactly the machine code that is produced from your source code if use the `LIST` compile option (see [this example output](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.3?topic=output-example-assembler-code-generated-from-source-code)). I recommend to always compile with options `LIST, MAP, OFFSET, XREF` because these options enable you find the exact problem in your Cobol source even when you only have a program dump from an abend.

Anyway, **good programming practice** is not to care about the compiler or the machine code, but about the other programmers who will have to maintain, and thus read and understand the code. Good practice would be to always prefer simple and readable instructions, and to document the reasons (right in the code) when deviating from this rule.

Comment: Excellent presentation. Your explanation lead me to understand that ADD requires 3 instructions whereas MOVE requires 1 instruction. As a result, one should use MOVE rather than ADD (as the question originally implied) - Am I correct?

Comment: `AP     SOME_RESULT,TEMP` would add `TEMP` to `SOME_RESULT`, The instruction should be `ZAP    SOME_RESULT,TEMP`, which would first zero `SOME_RESULT` before the adding `TEMP`. An optimizing compiler should reduce the three instructions to something like `ZAP   SOME_RESULT,=P'16'`. But, I haven't touched IBM COBOL or Assembler in nearly 40 years. Also note, in reference to "I bet `SOME-RESULT` is a `packed-decimal` (or `COMP-3`) ...", that the source code was linked in the question and the actual data-item (`APPL-RESULT`) is `pic s9(9) comp`.

Comment: @RickSmith Using ZAP requires some optimization logic. Please see my note about the optimize compiler option. The origin of the ADD TO ZERO programming practice is older than the optimize compiler option! As to the source code, I didn't find SOME-RESULT there, so I made an assumption. But if it isn't COMP-3, or not part of an index key, then it's probably unknowingly adopted, either out of tradition or - even more probable - by copy and paste, as guessed in my answer.

Comment: @NoChance The ADD may compile into 2 instructions as well, but I believe it's 3. May also depend on the compiler options used. I don't have Cobol compiler at hand to verify this. I've added instructions to my answer how to do this yourself. But yes, you should use MOVE if you don't have specific reasons to use the ADD TO ZERO version.

Answer (score -2):

Some programmers like to do things "just because they can".  I have a feeling that is what you are seeing here.  It makes about as much sense as doing

```golang
a := 0 + b
```

would in go.

Comment: There are contexts, in some languages, where `0 + b` is not equivalent to `b`. It might explicitly coerce `b` to a numeric type, or it might fail to compile if `b` is not already numeric. That wouldn't apply to the code in the question, though.